# What is the use of a fill-column if most modern text editors can word-wrap?

Tags: emacs, fill, word-wrap, emacs23

I have my `emacs` fill-column set to almost 10 trillion (999999999999). Is that bad, or is there another way to make `emacs` have a virtually infinite fill-column?

What is the use of a fill-column anyways? Why would one want that sort of line wrapping?

Comment: Turn off auto-fill if you don't want it.

Comment: I think that `fill-column` has something to do with displays being
rectangular and not just a 1D line of text. Is your display different?:)

Comment: Use `most-positive-fixnum` when you need the largest integer possible.

Comment: @phils: thanks, but when I use "M-x set-fill-column" and put "most-positive-fixnum" it says "Please enter a number."

Comment: Ah, I presumed you were setting it in code, not interactively. `most-positive-fixnum` is a system-dependent elisp constant.

Comment: I think @phils meant "Use the ***value*** of `most-positive-fixnum`", not the symbol itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have a gigantic `fill-column`.  Or yes, you can turn off `auto-fill-mode` (use `(auto-fill-mode -1)` or set `auto-fill-function` to `nil`).

"That sort of line wrapping" is useful if you want text that has lines of limited length. (Duh.)

See also `visual-line-mode`, which can give you a similar visual effect but without the insertion of hard newlines.

Comment: Well, even if I turn off auto-fill-mode, AucTeX, e.g., still uses fill-column for its own LaTeX formatting, so it seems the only way to make AucTeX not fill is to make fill-column as big as possible.

Comment: Also, the other part of my question pertains to why do people like hard-wrapping in the first place? It seems like a holdover from typewriter days.

Comment: I can't comment on what AucTeX does with `fill-column`, sorry. Wrt why people want newline chars inserted: it's because the text they are writing needs to have such chars delimiting lines. If the text you write does not need to have lines separated by newline chars, then you don't need to limit line length. You can write everything in one giant line -- no problem.